# Getting multiple div content

Tags: jquery

I have html structure like this:

```
 <div class='inside'>
    <div>429185</div>
    <div>492128</div>               
 </div>
```

Sometimes there is only one div inside. I need to get both numbers, and to send them via ajax to php script. Here is how ajax look like:

```
var value_of_divs = jQuery(".inside div").text();

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        action: 'someaction',
        code: value_of_divs
    },
    url: '/somescript.php',
    success: function(msg) {
    jQuery('#somediv').html(msg);
    }
});
```

But as you can see, this works only when one div is in "inside" div. When two divs are there (like in example), i get nothing from php script. How to pickup content of both divs (as array?) and to send them to ajax?

Comment: You can't send JavaScript arrays via Ajax. Do you mean JSON?

Comment: I dont know, maybe... Whatever, i changed title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var value_of_divs = $.map($('.inside div'), function (div) {
    return div.innerHTML
});
```

Comment: Or `$( '.inside div' ).map(function () { return $( this ).text(); }).get()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var value_of_divs = [];

jQuery(".inside div").each(function(){
    value_of_divs.push(jQuery(this).text());

});

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        action: 'someaction',
        code: value_of_divs
    },
    url: '/somescript.php',
    success: function(msg) {
    jQuery('#somediv').html(msg);
    }

});
```